# How can I kill all processes that were started with my user account using a BAT file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a "self-destruct" script that will delete my user folder when someone tries to illicitly access my files. I do not have administrator rights, but I do have permission to remove my own user folder. Windows won't let me delete it if a process is accessing a file for obvious reasons, so what I want to try and do is quit all the processes running under my username so that I can delete the folder with no worries. Is there a way to do this with TASKKILL.exe?

Comment: Who is going to guarantee that only processes running under your username are accessing your profile directory?

Comment: Is this in a business environment or maybe a school?  What other reasons are there not to have administrator permissions?  You do know that files and folders can be restored after deletion, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should forcefully kill any task of user `MyUser`:

```
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq MyUser"
```

**References:**

- [Taskkill documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)

Comment: It will kill the batch file that is running taskkill too, so any deletions by it won't happen.

Comment: I have tried using `taskkill /f /fi "IMAGENAME ne cmd.exe"` but even that closes the cmd window.

Comment: Marking the answer as correct because it answers the question, although it does not solve my problem.

Comment: I know this is a bit of an old question but I found it useful. +1.
I found you can chain the filters as follows: `taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq MyUser" /fi "IMAGENAME ne cmd.exe"`
Hopefully this helps.
Also, the recommended documentation has changed - it is now here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill